# Spring Boot - Detect and terminate if property not set?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any way for a Spring Boot web application to abort at startup if a required property is not set anywhere (neither in the application.properties file nor the other property sources)?  Right now, if the property is included in another property, it seem that Spring Boot simply avoids substitution.

For example, in my application.properties file, I have the line:

```
quartz.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:${my.home}/database/my-jobstore
```

Right now, if "my.home" is not set elsewhere, Spring Boot is setting the url literally to *"jdbc:hsqldb:${my.home}/database/my-jobstore"* (no substitution).

I would like to have the application fail to start if the property `my.home` were not set anywhere else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To throw a friendly exceptions just put a default null value in property,  check and throw a exception in afterProperty method.

```
@Component
public static class ConfigurationGuard implements InitializingBean {

@Value("${my.home:#{null}}")
private String myHomeValue;

public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    if (this.myHomeValue == null or this.myHomeValue.equals("${my.home}") {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("${my.home} must be configured");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: imho this must be the accepted answer, as it does what OP has asked for: check for a configuration property, and throw an initialization-time error (exception) with a friendly message if none. In most of my enterprise apps, I am following exactly the same approach, as it allows to gracefully handle incomplete configuration. One extra tip here would be to add a ``@Configuration`` annotation on your config-check class so it is loaded before any beans.

Answer (score 5):

Create a bean with a simple `@Value(${my.home})` annotated field. - Then Spring will try to inject that value and will fail and therefore stop when the value is not there.

---

*Just `@Value(${my.home}) private String myHomeValue;` is enough for normal (not Boot) Spring applications for sure! But I do **not know** whether Boot has some other configuration to handle missing values: If there is an other failure management than you could check that value in an PostCreation method.*

```
@Component
public static class ConfigurationGuard implements InitializingBean {

   @Value(${my.home})
   private String myHomeValue;

   /**
    * ONLY needed if there is some crude default handling for missing values!!!!
    *
    * So try it first without this method (and without implements InitializingBean)
    */
   public void afterPropertiesSet() {
      if (this.myHomeValue == null or this.myHomeValue.equals("${my.home}") {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("${my.home} must be configured");
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work as expected.  Instead, it throws a BeanCreationException when trying to resolve the ${my.home} in the @Value annotation (which, by the way, needs to be surrounded in quotes: @Value("${my.home}").  So, while I get an exception, I don't have control over the exception (e.g., I can't show a custom message).  I also can't shut down the entire web app immediately.

Comment: @David H: But isn't that `BeanCreationException` what you want if the property isn't there *"...way for a Spring Boot web application to abort at startup if a required property is not set anywhere..."* ?  (then you don't need the `afterPropertiesSet` method)

Comment: `@Ralph -- yes that's true; I was hopeful that I could somehow terminate the program with a nice error message ("You forgot to set the variable!") rather than an ugly stack trace.  But now that you mention it, I guess I could just put a try/catch on the Application.run().

Comment: Stack traces are beautiful for diagnosing issues.  They tell you exactly where something failed as opposed to error messages that can be deceiving and don't pinpoint the failure.

Answer (score 3):

The default behaviour in current versions of Spring Boot (1.5.x, 2.0.x, 2.1.x) is to throw an exception if a placeholder can not be resolved.

There will a be an exception like this one :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.foo.undefined' in value "${app.foo.undefined}"

It works because a bean of type `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (from spring-context) is automatically registered in Spring Boot, in this class : [`PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.html). And by default, the property `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` in `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is set to false, which means an exception must be thrown if a placeholder is unresolved (be it nested or not).

Comment: Strange. This doesn't seem to match my experience. Does it work if the variable has no dots? Like `${FOO}`.

Answer (score 3):

Although they work, I think the approach in the foremost answer is somewhat brittle, as it only works for the predefined name(s), and will silently stop checking the when someone changes `quartz.datasource.url` in the configs to use a different expansion.

Ideally, I want [this value of `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/248ad0fa796e2d3e611a166f68357a3d5d608ecf/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java#L173-L179) to be `false` to get wholesale expansion checking when parsing my configs such as `application.properties` or its YAML variants, but [it's hard-coded to `true`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3236dfd7d9141ed627a94ae1dc006d2c517d1a47/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/PropertySourcesPlaceholdersResolver.java#L51) for these cases.  This unfortunately leaves strings such as `${FOO}` in its unexpanded form if `FOO` cannot be found, making troubleshooting extremely painful.  This is especially the case for fields that don't readily appear in the logs such as passwords.

While I couldn't find a way of changing `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` short of modifying Spring Boot's classes, I did find an alternative of using a custom `PropertySource` implementation and defining a new syntax such as "`${!FOO}`" to indicate `FOO` must exist as an environment variable or die.  (The OP didn't mention whether `my.home` is an environment variable but the code below is for environment variables.)

First, an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` implementation is required for registering the custom `PropertySource`.  This `StrictSystemEnvironmentProcessor.java` does this as well as holds the implementation of the custom `PropertySource`:

```
package some.package;

@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
class StrictSystemEnvironmentProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "STRICT_" + StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME;

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        if (environment.getPropertySources().contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
            return;
        }

        SystemEnvironmentPropertySource delegate = (SystemEnvironmentPropertySource)environment.getPropertySources()
                .get(StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME);

        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(new StrictSystemEnvironmentPropertySource(delegate));
    }

    private static class StrictSystemEnvironmentPropertySource extends SystemEnvironmentPropertySource {

        public StrictSystemEnvironmentPropertySource(SystemEnvironmentPropertySource delegate) {
            super(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, delegate.getSource());
        }

        @Override
        public Object getProperty(String name) {
            if (name.startsWith("!")) {
                String variableName = name.substring(1);
                Object property = super.getProperty(variableName);
                if (property != null) {
                    return property;
                }

                throw new IllegalStateException("Environment variable '" + variableName + "' is not set");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Instead of returning `null`, an exception is thrown for names that start with `!`.

This `META-INF/spring.factories` is also required so that Spring initializes our `EnvironmentPostProcessor`:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=some.package.StrictSystemEnvironmentProcessor
```

Then henceforth, I can write all environment variables substitutions in my configs as `${!FOO}` to get strict existance checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, and decorate it with `@Validated` and `@NotNull`. This will throw an exception during startup when the value is not present (or `null`), e.g.

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
public class MyProperties {
    @NotNull  
    private String home;

    // getter/setter, or constructor. See @ConstructorBinding.
}
```

For reference: [Spring Boot 2.6 - @ConfigurationProperties Validation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.validation).

Note that you may need to add `spring-boot-starter-validation`, or another validator, depending on your project.

Then, you can just supply it as a dependency when needed, e.g.

```
@Component
public class AnotherBean {
    private final MyProperties myProps;

    public AnotherBean(MyProperties myProps) {
        this.myProps = myProps;
    }

    // some code that uses myProps.getHome()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a more generic, plug-and-play solution to this issue. This is what I came up with:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class UnresolvedPlaceholderDetector {

    @EventListener
    public void handleContextRefreshed(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        var env = (ConfigurableEnvironment) event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        env.getPropertySources()
                .stream()
                .filter(ps -> ps instanceof MapPropertySource)
                .map(MapPropertySource.class::cast)
                .map(MapPropertySource::getPropertyNames)
                .flatMap(Stream::of)
                .forEach(pn -> {
                    // This throws IllegalArgumentException on unresolved placeholders
                    env.getRequiredProperty(pn);
                    log.debug("Property '{}' is resolved", pn);
                });
    }
}
```

Still needs a bit more testing for corner cases (e.g. non-`MapPropertySource` sources), but seems to work well to hard crash the app on any unresolvede placeholder anywhere from properties in config files. Example:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DB_HOST' in value "jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/test"`