# Spring boot mandatory environment variable

Tags: spring-boot

I have a setting that has no sensible default; I would like my application to refuse to boot if the setting is not supplied. Is there a natural way to achieve this in Spring Boot?

In my `application.yml` I'm using syntax like this:

```
    mySetting: "${MY_ENV_VAR}"
```

If I don't set the `MY_ENV_VAR` environment variable, the application continues booting and throws a somewhat obscure error.

Is there a recommended way to express my intent that this setting is mandatory?

Comment: This can possibly help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528697/spring-boot-detect-and-terminate-if-property-not-set

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to register a class that carries the `mySetting` property.

You can then mark this property as `@NotNull`. See also [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3510).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this, as well as adding `@Validated` to the class, and Spring still carries on with the `mySetting` property containing the literal string `myApp.${MY_ENV_VAR}`.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43372249/11812518

Answer (score 2):

Normally you have a property in `application.yaml` which you need somewhere in the application either as a String or Integer or another basic type.

You then later use the property in your application by using `@Value` inside your component.

So for example the following code is your component that needs this value, you can mark the component as `@Validated` so the validation annotations are considered and then on the specific property that you need to use the value mySetting you use the `@NotBlank`. Not blank means not empty string and not null string.

If the validation fails the component initialization will fail and so the application context will not complete and the startup will fail with a relative error pointing at this property.

```
@Component
@Validated
public class MyComponent {

@NotBlank
@Value(${mySetting})
private String mySetting;

....

}
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. How does this translate into an environment variable?

Comment: @Doradus by using the code above when you load the application you have mySetting: `"${MY_ENV_VAR}"` so if env variable is not set the property would be empty and load of application will fail